# How to style nth-child alternating in flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I like to build a grid-like construct where my first and every odd row have two flex elements by each other in f.e. 60% and 40% width and in my second and every even row these elements have opposite widths meaning 40% and 60% (reversed).

Sure I would define every element by hand, but when I just a frontend framework I like to generate these elements programmatically and that's where the struggle comes in.

I prepare the static version here: https://play.tailwindcss.com/dqiZBooPhQ

How can I determine which element gets the 60% and which gets the 40%?

Comment: You may style every 2nd and 3rd element in every quartet with arbitrary variant for width and use it in a loop like `<div class="h-20 w-2/5 [&:nth-child(4n+2)]:w-3/5 [&:nth-child(4n+3)]:w-3/5 bg-purple-400">1</div>`. Same should be apllied for bg-color if needed

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple sample with css flexbox for you

CSS:

```
div {
        min-width: 200px;
        height: 25px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .wrapper > div {
        display: flex;
    }       
    
    .wrapper > div:nth-child(even) {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f00;
    }
    .wrapper > div:nth-child(even) > div:first-child {
        width: 40%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .wrapper > div:nth-child(even) > div:last-child {
        width: 60%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #0f0;
    }
    .wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) > div:first-child {
        width: 60%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .wrapper > div:nth-child(odd) > div:last-child {
        width: 40%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

and HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
        <div class="a">test</div>
        <div class="b">test</div>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <div class="a">test</div>
        <div class="b">test</div>
    </div>
    <div id="third">
        <div class="a">test</div>
        <div class="b">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but these structure doesn't play well which a framework like angular where like to iterate elements in on level after each other

Comment: that's not right I use this in angular an vue, in angular with ng-for an vue with v-for and i use scss